# Как заблокировать ифрейм

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть ифрейм в котором может находится флеш-файл/видео. Как мне заблокировать содержимое ифрейма и разблокировать его лишь по клику, а по клику снова заблокировать? Есть атрибут sandbox, но он работает лишь в хроме и сафари. Есть ли какое-нибудь кроссбраузерное решение?

Answer (score 2):

А если не блокировать, а прятать ифрейм?

```
<a href="http://ya.ru" target="frame">ya.ru</a>
<a href="http://yandex.ru"target="frame">yandex.ru</a>
<a href="about:blank"target="frame">about:blank</a>\

<iframe width="500" height="500" name="frame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Comment: Можно и спрятать и при клике вызывать, но чтобы он не был активен.

Comment: Я изменил свой ответ. Теперь там есть кусок кода с фреймом, под именем frame. Сначала фрейм - about:blank (то есть пустой). При нажатии на ссылку эта ссылка открывается во фрейме (об этом говорит target="frame").